# How to check sent by web requests during UI testing without mocking

Tags: karate

I perform UI testing and want to check if the UI actions lead to the correct API request. I would not like to change them. Is there a way to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at the interceptor support in karate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driverintercept - maybe you can combine this with the approach here: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935 - but you may need to do some digging and contribute code etc.

Comment: @PeterThomas As I understand once request be intercepted they will not be sent to the server at all. Am I wrong? So I need to perform the same request from mock-feature and return the real response.

Comment: can you please read that first link and see the section `Intercepting All Requests` thanks. beyond that I don't have ideas, please assume this is unsupported